# Laravel Sessions: Why does my function load the old session?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm working on a shopping cart function using session. I am trying to make  function that update the quantity of an item in  shopping cart and reload the subtotal and the cart's items list on header of the page.The function update the session and reload the subtotal but the problem is that it reload the cart's items list with the old session's information (before i updated). I want it to get the new session's information. Could you give me any ideas how to fix this? Many thanks!

I tried js `setTimeout($('#cart-button').load(),2000)` to delay the function to see if it can get the new session but it's still not working.

P/s: I 've just tried to put `$this->ajaxReloadCart($cart->totalQty, $this->money($cart->totalPrice), $cart->items);` in subOneItem() function, it works fine but the cart list is now at the subtotal div

**Here is my js function**:

```
$('#sub-1-{{$item['item']['id']}}').click(function(){
                    var qty = $('#qty-{{$item['item']['id']}}').val();
                    var int_qty = parseInt(qty);
                    if(int_qty > 1){
                        int_qty--;
                        $('input#qty-{{$item['item']['id']}}').val(int_qty);
                        $('#sub-total').load('sub-one/{{$item['item']['id']}}');
                        $('#cart-button').load('reload-mini');
                     }
                     if(int_qty <= 1){
                        int_qty = 1;
                     }

                });
```

**My routes**

```
Route::get('sub-one/{id}','PageController@subOneItem');
Route::get('reload-mini','PageController@reloadMiniCart');
```

and **my controller functions**:

-**ajaxReloadCart**:

```php
public function ajaxReloadCart($totalQty, $totalPrice, $items){
        echo '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    <a href="view-cart">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i>
                        <div class="item-number">'
                            .$totalQty.
                        '</div>
                    </a>
                </button>';
        echo   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>';
        echo '  <ul class="dropdown-menu cart-items-list" id="cart-items-list">';
        foreach($items as $item){
            $price = $this->money($item['item']['price']);
            echo '  <li>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-left:0; margin-top:10px;">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <img src="upload/product/'.$item['item']->productimg->first()->name.'" width="100" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                            <div class="row">
                                <a href="product/'.$item['item']['id'].'"><strong>'.$item['item']['name'].'</strong></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">'
                                .$price.' X '.$item['qty'].
                            '</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </li>';
        }
        echo '  <li><a><strong>Subtotal:</strong>&nbsp; <div class="pull-right">'.$totalPrice.'</div></a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li><li><a href="#">To Checkout</a></li></ul>';
    }
```

-**subOneItem**:

```php
 public function subOneItem($id){
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

        $cart->subOne($product, $id);
        Session::put('cart',$cart);


        $totalPrice = $this->money($cart->totalPrice);
        // display mini cart and total price
        echo $totalPrice;

    }
```

-**reloadMiniCart**:

```php
    public function reloadMiniCart(){
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

        $this->ajaxReloadCart($cart->totalQty, $this->money($cart->totalPrice), $cart->items);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the session first before you assign the new cart values to the session
with `Session::forget('cart');` or clear all session with `Session::flush()`

then assign the new cart info to session

in your subonitem() function after 
`Session::put('cart',$cart);`

add `Session::save()`;

Comment: still not working. I don't think it's the problem because i have addToCart function which works the same way and still reload the cart list with the updated data.

Comment: here is my addToCart function:

```
public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id){

        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->id);
        Session::put('cart',$cart);
        $this->ajaxReloadCart($cart->totalQty, $this->money($cart->totalPrice), $cart->items);
    }
```

Comment: I 've just tried to put $this->ajaxReloadCart($cart->totalQty, $this->money($cart->totalPrice), $cart->items); in subOneItem() function, it works fine but the cart list is now at the subtotal div.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: so your $total price is updated? but not the list of items in the cart?

Comment: **the session and $totalprice** are updated, but **reloadMiniCart() function** still get the old session's data

Comment: see my answer above, try `Session::save()`;

Comment: it's not working. Can you tell me the difference between Session::save() and Session::put().? I thought Session::put() can also save session's data.

Comment: I found other way to do it.but i think it's not the best way.
anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found other way to get the cart list reloaded but i think it's not the best way.
if you guys find any other ways, please comment below. I want to find a better way.

my solution:
reload cart list every 1s

```
setInterval(function(){
        $('#cart-button').load('reload-mini');
    },1000);
```